# How do the Sanders Campaign economic growth models compare to the work of Gerald Friedman?

Tags: united-states, election, economy, data-sources

Recently a group of former Chairs of the Council of Economic Advisers for Democratic presidents released an [open letter](https://lettertosanders.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/open-letter-to-senator-sanders-and-professor-gerald-friedman-from-past-cea-chairs/) criticizing the use of Gerald Friedman's work by the Bernie Sanders presidential campaign. They offered a harsh criticism saying

> Friedman asserts that your plan will have huge beneficial impacts on growth rates, income and employment that exceed even the most grandiose predictions by Republicans about the impact of their tax cut proposals.

The sanders campaign has been [very open](https://berniesanders.com/issues/how-bernie-pays-for-his-proposals/) about how they propose to pay for their proposals. Obviously how they pay for their proposals is highly dependent on economic forecasting both on the cost side and taxation side. Freideman's work was not "commissioned by the Sanders campaign, but the campaign’s policy manager called the report ['outstanding work.'](http://usuncut.com/news/top-economist-believes-bernie-sanders-plan-will-raise-income-and-lower-unemployment/)"

My question is this, do the cost estimates and tax estimates put forth by the Sanders campaign use Friedman's estimates of economic growth, unemployment, and healthcare costs? If not, how much do the estimates used by the Sanders campaign to document their funding proposals differ from those put forth by Friedman?